# unity how to count turns to change players

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I would like to make a bowling game in unity and I want to change the players after they threw the ball two times and the whole game to continue for 4 turns.
so I have two balls and each one has a script with a playerController that moves around the balls and after collision they respawn in the original position. 
so for the turns I made a gameController that enables player1 (ball) input and disables player2 input then it enables player2 and disables player1. 
How can I make player 1 to play twice and then change to player 2.

the script is:

```
public IEnumerator gamePlay()
{
    if (pl1.hasPlay == false)
    {            
        pl1.gameObject.SendMessage("Activate");
        pl2.gameObject.SendMessage("Deactivate");
    }

    if (pl1.hasPlay == true)
    {

        pl2.gameObject.SendMessage("Activate");
        pl1.gameObject.SendMessage("Deactivate");

    }
    yield return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using two integers: one to store the number of plays and another to store the number of rounds.

It would look like this:

```
private int plays;
private int rounds;

private void Start()
{
    plays = 0;
    rounds = 0;
    StartCoroutine(gamePlay());
}

public void NextBall()
{
    plays++;
    // Here you can change the logic behind the 2 balls
    // (I remember it changes depending on whether you did a strike or not, if it's your last play or not, ...)
    if (plays >= 2)
    {
        plays = 0;
        rounds++;
        StartCoroutine(gamePlay());
    }
}

public IEnumerator gamePlay()
{
    // This is based on player 1 being the first player
    pl1.hasPlay = (rounds % 2 == 0);
    pl2.hasPlay = !pl1.hasPlay;

    pl1.gameObject.SendMessage(pl1.hasPlay ? "Activate" : "Deactivate");
    pl2.gameObject.SendMessage(pl2.hasPlay ? "Activate" : "Deactivate");

    yield return 0;
}
```

Also i'm not sure why you declared `gamePlay()` as an **IEnumerator** and not as a method but I guess you needed it this way :)

I changed the `if/else` condition by a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) since the content on both part was similar, I find it easier to read like this.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: I think this is the logic I need but where does next player method is called?

Comment: You can call it when the ball is re-spawned I think.